# In ipython, how can I type multiple lines before it interpret what I wrote?

Tags: python, ipython, with-statement

In ipython, sometimes I want to type multiple lines and be able to go back in history and call it again. The problem is that it execute right upon pressing return. I am using `\` before pressing return, but need to remove it.

Comment: How about trying `%rep`? Does that do what you need?  (Via - https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/api/generated/IPython.history.html)

Comment: Type `(` and hit Enter. Arrow up, backspace the `(`. Now you have multi-line input and as long as you don't hit Enter on the last `...:` line you can add more lines. Not the prettiest but it works.

Comment: Looking at the possibilities of `ipython`, I now think of trying [vim-python](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython).

Answer (score 0):

I had the idea of creating an empty `with` so my statements are in a block. Yeah, but what is an empty `with` ???

noop! So here's my noop:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# noop to use in with statement, so that ipython does not execute uppon pressing enter.

class noop(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass
```

You can place it in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/noop.py` to let you use it directly, like so:

```py
with noop():
    x=None
    print(x)
```

It would be great to have two typing modes. Changing mode for an empty line, and have the prompt reflect this state